# Reference request: Inversions and $\sum_{w\in W}q^{\ell(w)}$ for arbitrary Coxeter groups

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

For the symmetric group $S_n$, an *inversion* of a permutation $\pi∈S_n$ is a pair $1\leq i<j\leq n$ such that $\pi(i)>\pi(j)$. It is known that the length $\ell(\pi)$ of a permutation (i.e. the least number of simple transpositions needed to express $\pi$) coincide with its number of inversions. This is useful to compute
$$\sum_{\pi\in S_n}q^{\ell(\pi)} = (n)_q!$$
What happens if I replace $S_n$ by an arbitrary finite Coxeter group? Is there still a notion for an inversion? What is the above sum in this case?

**Edit** Okay, to be able say that I have my homework done, here some thoughts on the problem: A general definition of the inversion number for Weyl groups seems to be the following: The inversion number of a word $w$ is its number of positive roots that are mapped to negative roots. This still equals its length $\ell(w)$.

**Example: $B_n$** For this group this seems to be easy (since I can draw pictures in my head for what it does…): It is simply the group $S_n$ with one additional generator that flips let's say the first sign in a sequence.

Apart from permuting elements, we may flip zero to $n$ signs, where we have $n$ possibilities for the first sign, $n-1$ for the second etc. So for $B_n$, the required polynomial should be

$$\sum_{w\in B_n}q^{\ell(w)} = (1+nq + (n-1)q^2 + \cdots + q^n)(n)_q!$$

which coincides with counting the elements explicitly (at least, for $B_2$)

- Is there a nicer way to express this number?
- Is there a general systematic, e.g. how to obtain this from the presentation?
- Is there a listing for other Coxeter groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might be well aware, given a Coxeter group $W$, the Poincare polynomial is defined to be
$$
W(q)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nq^n=\sum_{w\in W}q^{\ell(w)},
$$
where $a_n=|\{w\in W:\ell(w)=n\}|$.

One place where computations of the Poincare polynomials can be found is in the paper "[A combinatorial derivation of the Poincare polynomials of the finite irreducible Coxeter groups](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X00003757)" by Rudolf Winkel. It covers types $A_n, B_n, D_n$, and the other exceptional types.

Some other basic results about Poincare polynomials/series can be found in Sections 1.11 and 5.12 of Humphreys' *Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups*.

Comment: I was not aware that this polynomial has a name. This faciliates searching. But how does one see that one new generator in type D contributes $(1+q^{n-1})(n)_q$? I Always compute $(1+q^{n+2})(n)_q$, which seems to be wrong.